# FileReader onload and assign value in loop?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

i'm having difficulties on getting file reader content assignment. Is there anyway to wait the file reader finish onload and assign the file content before it push to the array?

I have a list of input file type button as below:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < @Model.LetterList.Count(); i++)
{
  <tr>
     <td>
         <input type="file" id="LetterAttachment" name="LetterAttachment" accept="application/pdf">
     </td>
  </tr>
}
```

[image]

When i click submit, i want to assign the file content value into my form list in loop, below is my javascript code :

```
var attach=""; // empty variable for assign file content
function ApproverAction(action) {

        var formList = [];

        $("input[name='LetterAttachment']").each(function () {

            if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

                // I perform file reader here to assign the file content into attach....
                var FR = new FileReader();
                FR.onload = function (e) {
                    attach = e.target.result;
                }    
                FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                 var form = {
                        ID: newGuid(),
                        FileContents: attach, <<< ---- However it showing empty 
                        DocumentName: this.files[0].name,
                        DocumentSize: this.files[0].size,
                        DocumentContentType: 'application/pdf',
                        SourceType: 'OnlineAssessment',
                        CreatedDate: '@DateTime.Now'
                }

                formList.push(form);
            }

        });

        console.log(formList);
}
```

However i can't get the result quite correctly for output :

[image]

Any help and tips is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a promise for each file that resolves in the onload function and push those promises into an array

Then  use `Promise.all()` to send the data once all promises have resolved. Note that the error handling will need to be improved depending on process flow you want

```
function ApproverAction(action) {

  var filePromises = [];

  $("input[name='LetterAttachment']").each(function() {

      if (this.files && this.files[0]) {

         // reference to this to use inside onload function
         var _input = this;

        var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

            var FR = new FileReader();               

            FR.onload = function(e) {    
              var form = {
                ID: newGuid(),
                FileContents: e.target.result;,
                DocumentName: _input.files[0].name,
                DocumentSize: _input.files[0].size,
                DocumentContentType: 'application/pdf',
                SourceType: 'OnlineAssessment',
                CreatedDate: '@DateTime.Now'
              }    

              // resolve promise with object
              resolve(form);
            }
            FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

            if(FB.error){
              //   needs more robust error handling, for now just reject promise
              reject(FB.error)
            }
            // push promise to array
            filePromises.push(promise)
          }

        });         
    }

  });
  // return a new promise with all the data
  return Promise.all(filePromises)
     
}
```

---

Usage with promise returned from function

```
ApproverAction(action).then(function(formList){
      // do something with the data array
      console.log(formList);         
      
}).catch(function(err){
      console.error("Ooops something went wrong')
});
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback, currently i'm trying your solution but i get error at _input.files[0].name and size as it shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined". May i know why?

Comment: Ohhhh. I made a dumb mistake. Move `var _input = this;` **above** new Promise! See update in answer

Comment: thanks alot ! Although i did not fully use the code, but i already got the concept and used it for reference! Will mark this as answer! Have a great day!

Comment: hmm i found out it return undefined array list, do you have any idea?

Comment: Not really without a demo that reproduces it. Can put one in jsfiddle or other sandbox site probably failry quickly

Comment: Hi, fyi i already able to return the result, i have typo in the code and it sucks :( thanks for your help by the way!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the function you provided within the `FR.onload` is executed asynchronously. So, the code after it will be executed before the function is called thus the value of `FileContents` in the JSON is empty.

What you can do is either do all the stuff you want to do within the function or use some other function like `readAsText`.

```
...
                var FR = new FileReader();
                FR.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);

                 var form = {
                        ID: newGuid(),
                        FileContents: FR.readAsText(this.files[0),
                        DocumentName: this.files[0].name,
                        DocumentSize: this.files[0].size,
                        DocumentContentType: 'application/pdf',
                        SourceType: 'OnlineAssessment',
                        CreatedDate: '@DateTime.Now'
                }
...
```

Refer to this example for [onLoad](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload) and [readAsText](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText).

Comment: You can also go by charlietfl's code. It is how you can do all the action you want to do with the values within the function itself as I mentioned in my answer (*What you can do is either do all the stuff you want to do within the function *)

Comment: thank you for your feedback ! This have give me some insight too :)